# Finding the optimal teams ranking based on the table of match results

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, maximum

My original question was this:

> So my task is to score all the possible rankings of the 14 SEC
>   football teams and find the best one, using who won in head-to-head
>   games as the sole criterion (so not factoring in strength of schedule
>   or homefield advantage yet).
>
> RandomSample[Range[14]] gives me one random ranking of the 14 teams,
>   then I score that ranking by seeing how many wins and losses it
>   actually predicted. For example, if "1" represents Missouri (miss) and
>   "3" represents Georgia (ga), then if the generated ranking has 1
>   listed before 3, that ranking gets +1 to its ranking score, since
>   Missouri beat Georgia this season. If 3 is listed before 1, the
>   ranking score receives a -1 to its score, for incorrectly ranking
>   those teams with respect to each other. And so on for every
>   head-to-head SEC match up from last year.

In the code below, the 14x14 matrix is the head-to-head football results in the SEC from last year.  For example, since "1" represents Missouri and "3" represents Georgia, the entry (1,3) and (3,1) both represent Missouri vs. Georgia.  Since Missouri won, there's a 1 in that spot.  The code checks which number is in each entry, then if the generated list has the winning team in front of the loser, the ranking score k receives one point, minus one if not.  And it works for one list at a time.

Now I need a way to apply that algorithm to all 14! possible rankings (Permutations[RandomSample[Range[14]]), find the one with the highest ranking score (k) and show that ranking.

(14! is like 90 billion)

Here's the code

```
x = ({
    {0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
    {2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2},
    {1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 5},
    {1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0},
    {8, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 8, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9},
    {0, 0, 3, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 9, 0, 10, 10, 13, 10},
    {1, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0, 11, 11, 11},
    {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 12, 12},
    {1, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 13, 11, 12, 0, 13},
    {0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0}
   });

list1 = RandomSample[Range[14]];
rank = Ordering@list1;
k = 0;
For[i = 1, i < 15, i++,
 For[j = 1, j < 15, j++,
  Which[x[[i, j]] == i,
   If[rank[[i]] > rank[[j]], k++, k--],
   x[[i, j]] != (i || 0),
   If[rank[[j]] > rank[[i]], k++, k--]]]]; k
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to iterate over all 90 billion permutations? That's a lot of iterations. If I were you, I'd first ask on math.stackexchange.com whether there exists a more efficient algorithm that doesn't take superexponential time, and then implement that instead.

Comment: The 14! does seem like a lot but my professor seemed confident that it wouldn't be a big deal if I did it correctly.

Comment: I made a semi brute force approach that lead me to `{8,9,3,2,10,1,11,12,13,4,5,6,14,7}` but I think there must be a way to attack this with [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Comment: @RyanSummers I'm still at it. Don't forget to post your professor's answer when you get it ;)

Comment: My professor doesn't have the answer and wouldn't give it to me even if he did.  I have to come up with it "on my own."  I'm very new to programming so I've had to ask a lot of questions.

Comment: You can get a fairly good estimate of the best ranking as follows. (1) Rank the teams based on total number of wins. (2) Break ties by who won in head-to-head. The result may not be optimal according to the criteria above but it will be close. Among other things it can give a bound that is usable for pruning subsearches in a dynamic programming approach.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you don't want to evaluate 14! permutations. 
You could instead build up the top scoring ranking by recursively searching the following best candidate for the first place:

```
getFirstList[x_List, amng_List] :=
  Module[{among = Flatten@amng, score, labeled, reduced},
   score[el_]:= Module[{elr = Rest@el, 
                el1 = el[[1]]}, (Count[elr, el1] - Count[elr, Except[el1]] + Count[elr, 0])];
   labeled = MapThread[Join, {List /@ Range@Length@x, x}];
   reduced = Transpose[Transpose[labeled[[among]]][[Join[{1}, among + 1]]]];
   Select[reduced, score@# == Max[score /@ reduced] &][[All, 1]]
   ];
getFirstOne[x_List, amng_List] :=If[Length@# > 1, {First@getFirstList[x, #]}, #] &@
                                 getFirstList[x, amng]
getAllOrdered[x_List, {}] := {}
getAllOrdered[x_List, amng_List] := 
     Join[{#}, getAllOrdered[x, DeleteCases[amng, Alternatives @@ (Flatten@#)]]] &@
                                                                getFirstOne[x, amng]

Flatten@getAllOrdered[x, Range@14]
(*
 {8, 9, 1, 3, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14}
*)
```

The only problem is that the ranking function you provided doesn't generate unique results.
So,using the following function for the scoring of the rank:

```
calScore[x_List, rank_List] :=
 Total[
  Table[
   pre = rank[[;; i]];
   post = rank[[i ;;]];
   Which[
      MemberQ[pre, x[[rank[[i]], #]]], 1,
      MemberQ[post, x[[rank[[i]], #]]], -1,
      True, 0
      ] & /@ rank,
   {i, Length@rank}
   ], 2]
```

you can see that the ranking

```
{8,2,1,9,11,13,4,3,10,12,5,6,14,7}
```

has the same score (104) than our calculated one above